# Lcobucci\JWT\Parser is not instantiable while building LaravelPassport AccessTokenController after upgrading to Passport 10 Lcobucci JWT4.1

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-passport

Just upgraded to Laravel 8 / Laravel Passport 10.1 and Locbucci JWT 4.1.  I'm getting this error:

> Target [Lcobucci\JWT\Parser] is not instantiable while building [Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController]

This error makes sense since Parser is an interface, if I remove it from the AccessTokenController everything works as expected.  As far as I can tell these packages should work together.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error caused by the version of `Laravel/passport`, to solve this problem you must update to a new version of the package

execute this command, good luck

```
composer update laravel/passport
```